# Maximizing a function depending on 2 probability distributions.

Tags: calculus

Let $\{p_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ be a probability distribution. How one can find a distribution $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ that maximizes $\sum\limits_{1 \leqslant n \leqslant k} p_k \log(a_n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximizing with the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), we obtain the set of equations
$$ \sum_{k=n}^\infty p_k  = \lambda a_n, \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n} =1.$$

Solving the first equations for $a_n$ and plugging the solution into the second relation yields
$$1= \frac1\lambda \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty p_k =\frac1\lambda \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p_k $$ which determines $\lambda$.

Thus, we have the solution
$$a_n= \frac{\sum_{k=n}^\infty p_k}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty k p_k} =
\frac{1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p_k}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty k p_k}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Can Lagrange multipliers method be applied to functions with the infinite number of variables? And, did I get it correctly that in the beginning you didn't take into account "$a_n \geqslant 0$" constraints, but it happened so (luckily for us) that the final solution is non-negative?

Comment: @Alexey: yes, you can apply the method to an infinite number of variables. If you don't feel comfortable, just solve the problem with an upper limit $N$ and take $N\to \infty $ in the end. Regarding the boundary condition $a_n \geq 0$. A finite region for $a_n$ is best taken into account by first finding an extremum in the interior: if this is not possible, you have to check the values at the boundary. In this case, I would set $a_{n_0}=0$ if any one (or more) of the $a_n$ would turn out negative.